# Good PC car driving simulator?

Tags: simulation

I´m looking for a PC car driving simulator, **not a game**, but a software focused in good driving practices. Not browser based, I prefer a standalone application.

(If there is a real simulation **game**, I could use it, but if it is **just fun**, it´s not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: What sort of hardware are you intending to use, and what's the intended application here?  You can't get really accurate simulation using an arcade steering wheel.

Comment: @Shinrai: Simple PC with mouse / keyboard.

Comment: If you want to use a mouse/keyboard, you'll never do any serious skills training or safety instruction so I'm not why the emphasis on realism, hence my asking about your intended applications?  (I used to work for a driving school maintaining a few million dollars worth of simulation equipment - in my experience, especially examining potential equipment and software purchases, this is NOT something you can half-ass or it will never work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wogpRazlu8
http://www.autotrader.co.uk/CARS/buying/simulator.jsp

Comment: +1 The "Driving Test Success Practical Simulator PC Software" is really impressive.

Answer (score 3):

After looking for a while, and posting this same question in the SE gaming site, I found this software:

[3D Driving School](http://www.3dfahrschule.de/uk_index.htm). Demo available.

> Get driving experience step by
>   step:Training ground, right before
>   left, grant right of way, stop,
>   driving over traffic lights, turning
>   right and left correctly, mirror and
>   schoulder-checks etc.
>
> Drive during rain, snow, and in the
>   night.
>
> Big-city traffic. Mixed rules with a
>   higher traffic density.
>
> Fleet of vehicles for the different
>   driver license classes: Class B (5
>   cars), class S (2 quads), class A (3
>   motorcycles), and A1 with our Pantheon
>   scooter.
>
> Defensive training in Paris - don't
>   let yourself be provoked by our
>   traffic-rowdies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[TORCS](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/) is a Open Racing Car Simulator, which although a game, seems very realistic:

> ... simulation features a simple damage model, collisions, tire and wheel properties (springs, dampers, stiffness, ...), aerodynamics (ground effect, spoilers, ...) and much more.

Because of it's open nature, the game can be modified to suit your needs.

**Hardware Requirements**

- Minimum: 550MHz CPU, 128MB RAM, OpenGL 1.3 compatible graphics card with 32 MB RAM.
- Recommended: 800MHz CPU, 256MB RAM, OpenGL 1.3 compatible graphics card with 64 MB RAM.